# Download de pdfs de diferentes consultas de um site

Tags: r, download

Gostaria de baixar pdfs de diferentes consultas do seguinte site

[site para download dos dados](https://cadprev.previdencia.gov.br/Cadprev/faces/pages/modulos/dair/consultarDemonstrativos.xhtml)

Porém como o link não muda a cada consulta nova de município, não sei como fazer o download em escala para vários municípios, pois o pacote `curl` necessita de input do link para download e se ele não muda a cada consulta, não consigo efetuar o download em escala.

Tentei fazer da seguinte maneira

```
download.file("https://cadprev.previdencia.gov.br/Cadprev/faces/pages/modulos/dair/consultarDemonstrativos.xhtml", destfile = "C:/Users/holiveira/Desktop")
```

porém não consegui fazer o download, e também não consigo criar um mecanismo para dar escala.

Gostaria de ter um vetor com diversos nomes de municípios e fazer o download automatizado os arquivos pdf de todos

Comment: O link não muda mas o parametro viewstate muda, é só passar ele na requisição do post.

Comment: Desculpe a falta de conhecimento, poderia detalhar por favor, não conheço esse parâmetro

Comment: Atualiza sua pergunta com como você tá fazendo que eu mostro pra você como precisa fazer, sua pergunta tem poucas informações.

Comment: atualizada, obrigado pela disponibilidade